# Paypal Subscribe button in Mobile Site

Tags: php, paypal

Paynow button is redirecting to mobile version of paypal from mobile devices, where as subscribe button is showing the desktop versions with responsive manner.

Please let me know if the mobile and desktop versions are same for subscribe button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unsupported Use Cases**

Mobile PayPal Payments Standard is in the process of extending support for the merchant customizations listed below. Until then your customers will still be able to make payments via mobile devices but will not be presented with the mobile optimized checkout experience.

For now only merchants integrated with '**Buy Now**' buttons or third party shopping carts (using “**Cart Upload**”) will benefit from Mobile PayPal Payments Standard unless they use a customization listed below.

Merchant Customizations that are currently not supported:

Instant Update API, Buyer Supplied Price, Desc, Qty ,Discounts, Payment Type: Auth, Order and Inventory Management

Comment: Do you have any info on it to get the mobile version on subscription